# Delegating EJB to a Controller class rather than having it in a Servlet directly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am trying to not have an EJB injected in my Servlet, currently I am having it directly injected into my Servlet and it works fine but I want to pass control to a controller class that will inject the EJB, and not have a Controller method or constructor that takes a reference variable of the Bean and working with it. Everything I am doing is in JSP, and I try using the @ManagedBean annotation on my Controller but nothing works. I am using only JSPs and not JSF as I am not familiar with them. Is what I am trying to do achievable and is there an alternative to this besides passing reference of the bean ? Any shed of light is highly appreciated. Thank you. Currently what I have is the following in my Servlet.

```
 package com.ejb.web;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.ejb.EJB;
 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import com.ejb.customer.domain.Customer;
 import com.ejb.customer.service.CustomerLocal;
 import com.ejb.customer.util.DateUtil;

 /**
   * Servlet implementation class Servlet
 */
   @WebServlet("/customer")
   public class Dispatcher extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @EJB
 CustomerLocal customerLocal;

   /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
      public Dispatcher() {
        super();
     }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    throws ServletException, IOException {


    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
    String dateOfBirth = request.getParameter("dateOfBirth");

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName(name);
    customer.setSurname(surname);
    customer.setDateOfBirth(DateUtil.convertToDate(dateOfBirth));

    System.out.println("Starting .....Adding");
    System.out.println(customerLocal);
        customerLocal.addCustomer(customer);
    System.out.println("Done .....Adding");
    request.setAttribute("customers",customerLocal.getCustomers());

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");

    rd.forward(request, response);

 }


}
```

And what I want to achieve is something along these lines.

```
 package com.ejb.web;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.ejb.EJB;
 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import com.ejb.customer.domain.Customer;
 import com.ejb.customer.service.CustomerLocal;
 import com.ejb.customer.util.DateUtil;

 /**
   * Servlet implementation class Servlet
 */
   @WebServlet("/customer")
   public class Dispatcher extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Inject
 Controller controller;

   /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
      public Dispatcher() {
        super();
     }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    throws ServletException, IOException {


    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
    String dateOfBirth = request.getParameter("dateOfBirth");

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName(name);
    customer.setSurname(surname);
    customer.setDateOfBirth(DateUtil.convertToDate(dateOfBirth));

    System.out.println("Starting .....Adding");
    System.out.println(customerLocal);
        ccontroller.addCustomer(customer);
    System.out.println("Done .....Adding");
    request.setAttribute("customers",controller.getCustomers());

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");

    rd.forward(request, response);

 }


}
```

Where the controller class does something like the following.

```
    package com.ejb.customer.util;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import com.ejb.customer.domain.Customer;
    import com.ejb.customer.service.CustomerLocal;

     @ManagedBean
      @SessionScoped
    public class Controller {

 @EJB
 CustomerLocal customerLocal;

public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
customerLocal.addCustomer(customer);
}

public List getCustomers() {
    return customerLocal.getCustomers();
}

    }
```

Sorry about the poor indentation

Comment: Do you have any exception? Have you tried using CDI beans instead of ManagedBean?

Comment: Hi Jakub Hr, thank you for the reply, yes I get a NPE error which shows that the controller and the bean are not being instantiated, I haven't tried using CDI, I shall give that a try

Comment: That will probably work better, since @ManagedBean is not going to do much if you don't use a framework that supports it (most notably: JSF).

Comment: Thank Gimby, I didn't know I had to use a framework to support @ManagedBean, I shall do it once I start off doing JSF, currently I wanted to do everything with using JSF, just JSPs only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this code compiles, then you're referencing a different controller class.  You're injecting a Controller from the com.ejb.web package but the controller you have here is from the com.ejb.customer.util package.  You can also get rid of the ManagedBean reference since you're using a CDI scope.

If you want to use this controller in a JSF page, then use @Named instead of @ManagedBean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mamboking, in this do I have an option not to use JSF at all ? Because I haven't started doing them I just wanted to see if I can do it using JSPs.

Comment: It works the same way with JSPs. Add an @Named and then you'll be able to reference your controller in the JSP.  However, you really should consider JSF.  JSP is only included in the newer java ee's for backwards compatibility.